# Replace window.top with google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to make it work:

```
window.top = window;
```

In google chrome extension. It is not possible in native JavaScript, but may be extensions allow such low level operations.

Comment: first, read the relevant tab and windows apis in chrome.

Comment: I didn't find it in apis.

Comment: if you are attempting to focus a window look at those apis, its there.